# Interface Segregation Principle

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm learning SOLID principles with Java and I'm trying to implement two classes with this. My problem is about ISP. I have some methods that is present in one class but not in the other and I also have to refer both classes with the same interface.
This is the first class:

```
public final class Complex implements Number {
    @Override
    public String polarForm() {
        //This class needs to implement this method
    }

    @Override
    public String rectangularForm() {
        //This class needs to implement this method
    }
}
```

Here is the second one:

```
public final class Real implements Number {
    @Override
    public String polarForm() {
        //This class does not need this method!
    }

    @Override
    public String rectangularForm() {
        //This class does not need this method!
    }
}
```

Finally I have to refer to the classes something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number c = new Complex();
    Number r = new Real();
    Number n = c.add(r);
    System.out.println(c.polarForm());
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

How can I refer to both classes with the same interface without implementing unnecessary methods?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I _refer_ _to_ _both_ _classes_ with the same interface _without_ implementing _unnecessary_ _methods_?

Comment: I think the question is "how do I fulfill the interface segregation principle," in which case, we need to create a couple more specific interfaces that Real and Complex can implement.

Comment: If you want `polarForm()` do be a method on `Number`, where you don't know if it's a `Complex` or `Real` number, what do you expect `polarForm()` to do if called on a `Real`? If your answer is "not allowed", then method `polarForm()` doesn't belong on `Number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution to approach this problem would be to use *Composition* instead of *Inhertiance* in conjunction to the interface segregation principle.

**Number class**

```
public class Number {
    private RectangleForm rectangleForm;
    private PolarForm polarForm;
    private BigDecimal value;

    public Number(RectangleForm rectangleForm, PolarForm polarForm,BigDecimal value) {
        this.rectangleForm = rectangleForm;
        this.polarForm = polarForm;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String polarForm() {
        return polarForm.transform(this.value);
    }

    public String rectangleForm() {
        return rectangleForm.transform(this.value);
    }

    //other methods such as add and subtract
}
```

**PolarForm interface**

```
public interface PolarForm {
    public String transform(BigDecimal number);
}
```

**RectangularForm interface**

```
public interface RectangleForm {
    public String transform(BigDecimal number);
}
```

**RectangleForm implementation for real numbers**

```
public class RectangleFormReal implements RectangleForm {

    @Override
    public String transform(BigDecimal number) {
        String transformed = "";
        //transfromed = logic to transform to rectangle form
        return transformed;

    }

}
```

**PolarForm implementation for Real numbers**

```
public class PolarFormReal implements PolarForm {

    @Override
    public String transform(BigDecimal number) {
        //return the number as is without any transformation
        return number.toString();   
    }

}
```

**Putting the pieces together**

```
public class NumberTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RectangleForm rf = new RectangleFormReal();
        PolarForm pf = new PolarFormReal();
        Number number = new Number(rf, pf,new BigDecimal(10));
        String rectangleForm = number.rectangleForm();
        String polarForm = number.polarForm();
    }
}
```

You can create the `PolarFormComplex` and `RectangleFormComplex` implementations  and wire the`Number` instance in a similar fashion. The advantage of this approach is that your code will always rely on the interface of the `Number` class (by interface I mean the public APIs) and you can chose the transformation strategy by injecting the corresponding `PolarForm` or `RectangleForm` instances into your `Number` instance at compile time as shown above or at runtime (via a factory)

Answer (score 2):

Break your `Number` interface (or base class) into multiple interfaces. The standard operations (add, subtract, etc) are in one; let's say `INumber`. `polarForm` and `rectangularForm` are part of another; let's say `IComplex`.

`Real` would implement `INumber`; `Complex` would implement `INumber` and `Icomplex`. You could then treat both as `INumber`.

If necessary, you could also create another interface that implements both.

Comment: This OP states this *"How can I refer to both classes with the same interface without implementing unnecessary methods?"*. One immediate problem with your approach is that the user of the API cannot rely on a single *Interface* i.e `Number`. If the user of the API wants to call the `polarForm` method, they would always need to have a reference of type `IComplex` or resort to casting the `Number` reference to `IComplex`, thus relying on multiple *Interfaces*.